# upload file on blobstore with go API

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, go, blobstore

I try to add files on the blobstore, i have found some examples with go but these are examples with a html template and i now send images from my react-native app that calls my api in go to add file on blobstore.

So how to add a file on blobstore with a file i get with `r.FormFile()` in go ?

example i have found :

```
func sampleHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // [START uploading_a_blob_2]
    var rootTemplate = template.Must(template.New("root").Parse(rootTemplateHTML))

    const rootTemplateHTML = `
<html><body>
<form action="{{.}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form></body></html>
`
    // [END uploading_a_blob_2]

    // [START uploading_a_blob_1]
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    uploadURL, err := blobstore.UploadURL(ctx, "/upload", nil)
    if err != nil {
        serveError(ctx, w, err)
        return
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    err = rootTemplate.Execute(w, uploadURL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf(ctx, "%v", err)
    }
    // [END uploading_a_blob_1]
}
```

Thank's :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to provide a small JSON API that your React Native app can call that will give you back an upload URL generated by `blobstore.UploadURL`. You should then be able to POST to the URL as normal.